# Always displaying Home screen before exiting the app

Tags: android, android-activity

I have a Home screen and a sliding menu.
When the app starts the Home screen is displayed.
If you open the menu and click on on item, a new Activity (A1) is launched. This new Activity A1 can launch an Activity A1b. In that case if the user presses the back button he should go back to A1.
If you select another item on the menu, I want A1 and A1b to be removed from the back stack.

But I want the user to always go back to the home screen on the last "back" pressed before exiting the app.

**Example**

Starting from Home, the user select A1 on the menu and then press a button on A1 to go to A1b.

Back stack is now: Home|A1|A1b

the user select an other item A2

Back stack is now: Home|A2.

To do that I was thinking of using the Tasks and set the appropriate flags to the intent when I launch a new Activity. But it doesn't work.

How am I supposed to implement that?

Answer (score 0):

What flags did you set?

Create a method for back button and put this in it:

```
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
    intent.addCategory(Intent.CATEGORY_HOME);
    intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
    startActivity(intent);
```

Comment: I'd like the logic to be managed automatically without to override the back method.
Maybe I haven't understood how it works but I was thinking having the Home activity in a task, then create a new task (flag Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK) with Activity A1. Then for me, Home is in Task0 and A1 in Task1. Then I launch A1b with no specific flag (so it should be in Task1 too). When I launch A2 I was thinking of clearing the Task1 with Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK so like that the Task0 with Home remains and now Task1 has only A2. So if I press back I should go back to home

Answer (score 0):

add "finish();"  inside onStop(){ } of all chield Activities.

like:

```
   @Override
   protected void onStop() {

    super.onStop();
    finish();

}
```

Comment: Don't think it's a good idea as the Activity is gonna be killed if the app is in the background (if the user switches in between apps)

Answer (score 0):

### EDIT

Doesn't work as the application appears twice in the "recent" apps.

---

### ORIGINAL POST

I found a solution thanks to [this article](https://blog.akquinet.de/2010/04/15/android-activites-and-tasks-series-intent-flags/).

Home Activity should be a single task.

**In the AndroidManifest**

```
<activity
    android:name=".HomeActivity"
    android:launchMode="singleInstance">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

        <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
    </intent-filter>
</activity>
```

Then the HomeActivity launch Activity A1 as normal, without any specific flags. Same for A1 launching A1b.
When we want to launch A2, we clear the current task:

```
intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
```

As HomeActivity is in his own Task (thanks to the "singleInstance" launch mode ([see doc](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#clear))) it's not affected and remains. So now A2 is launched and A1 and A1b are gone. If I press "back" the Home Activity is displayed.